# Width of layer formed from sphere $r = n$ fitted inside sphere $r = 4n$

Tags: geometry, 3d, volume

If a volume equivalent to a solid sphere of radius $n$ is pushed onto the surface of a sphere with radius $4n$, how wide is the layer that forms, expressed relative to the radius $n$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What have you tried? What seems to be the issue here? Is there some concept that you struggle with? Or is it the calculation not giving you the expected answer? Please provide more information, otherwise the question will be closed.

Comment: Is it on the inside or outside of the larger sphere ?

Comment: on the inside of the larger sphere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a new radius of $r$ for the amount inside the sphere that doesn't include the volume which has been pushed onto the inside of the sphere of radius $4n$. Its volume will be the original sphere volume less the volume of the matter added to its insides. Thus, using the formula for the volume of a sphere, we get that

$$\cfrac{4}{3}\pi r^3 = \cfrac{4}{3}\pi \left(4n\right)^3 - \cfrac{4}{3}\pi n^3 = \cfrac{4}{3}\pi \left(63n^3\right) \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

Dividing both sides by $\frac{4}{3}\pi$ and taking cube roots, we get that

$$r = \sqrt[3]{63} n \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

Thus, the width of the layer that forms would be the difference between the original & new radii, i.e.,

$$4n - r = \left(4 - \sqrt[3]{63}\right)n \tag{3}\label{eq3}$$

Comment: the volume of the r = n sphere is fitted on the inside of the sphere, not the outside

Comment: @J.Doe I assumed initially on the outside. However, I have now modified my answer for the added volume to be on the inside.

Comment: good answer, came to the same result, was thinking at the same time. 4 - third root of 63 is around 0.02n, right?

Comment: @J.Doe Yes, my Windows calculator says that $4 - \sqrt[3]{63} =  0.02094279210360814033547201225123$. Also, as you came to the same result, you may wish to add some details, such as what you did & were unsure of, to your question if you don't want it down voted & possibly closed.

Comment: the question is not a duplicate of an old one, why it would be closed or removed I don't know, but I know the answer now so it is not in my self-interest what stackexchange does with it, seems to be counter to the idea of collaborative Q&As to delete it tough, but others can do as they want

Comment: @J.Doe I'm still relatively new here, so hardly any kind of expert, but I believe the main issue is we don't want to become just a homework site. To help avoid this, we want to have people at least make a reasonable effort to solve the problems themselves first. If the user doesn't show this, & it just appears they are getting us to do their homework for them, then the question may be down voted & closed (I believe it might be closed specifically so other people can't use it for their homework). I hope this makes some sense to you. Perhaps someone else can explain it better & in more detail.

Comment: augmentations like calculators do your work for you, that is not negative, but it enables you to perform more with the limited resources you have. I have now already solved the question I had, your answer was very accurate and easily communicated, and is also now indexed on the web. if some person gets upset because of some preconceived idea of what is legitimate questions and what is not, that does not impact me so much, at all. I cannot stop luddites, even if I wanted to, because they get off from a sense of control (of course a reflection of slave mentality). so, everyone to their own.

Comment: @J.Doe For any relatively large site, which is mostly automated due to limited funds to have manual control, requires appropriate rules for it to operate properly. Also, we get a wide sort & range of people using this site, both for what we (& I suspect most people) would consider to be generally good & bad reasons. Unfortunately, this doesn't as easily allow the many variations & types of interactions to always be appropriately handled. Even if you don't agree with the policies here, & note your question is not necessarily closed, but might be, I hope you understand our reasons for them.

Comment: the upvote-downvote system is those appropriate rules, I am well educated in incentive systems, I do that for a living. the whole charade of "not for homework" is just so that a few trolls can go around and dictate outside of the rules that are already in place, have no time or energy to give them attention, they can do what they want, I do not care, I have already consumed what I was after